# Why is this valid Python code not valid Ansible Python code

Tags: python, ansible

The following Python code is valid. I can execute it in a Python shell, no syntax error. Python3 or Python2, both fine.

```
def test():
    x = {
        'x': '1',
        'y': '2',
        'z': '3',
    }
    s = ' '.join(f'{key}={value}' for (key, value) in x.items())
    return s
```

When I provision the same code using Ansible, Ansible reports invalid syntax in this function

```
TASK [lvm : Volume group] ******************************************************
[WARNING]: Skipping plugin (/home/ostraaten/git/tpelcm/ansible/roles/internal/b
ackup/filter_plugins/backup_filters.py) as it seems to be invalid: invalid
syntax (backup_filters.py, line 39)
^CAnsible failed to complete successfully. Any error output should be
visible above. Please fix these errors and try again.
```

The offending line is

```
s = ' '.join(f'{key}={value}' for (key, value) in x.items())
```

When I remove that line there are no syntax errors anymore. Why does Ansible consider this invalid syntax? How should this code be written in Ansible's Python?

Comment: What version of python is Ansible running?

Comment: try ```s = ' '.join([f'{key}={value}' for (key, value) in x.items()])```   the stuff in the ```join()``` function should be a list.

Comment: I think generator expressions were introduced in Python 2.4; those should be safe enough...

Comment: "Python3 or Python2, both fine"—That's not true. Python 2 does not support f-strings.

Comment: @khelwood nice catch there.

Comment: `f`-strings were added to Python in Python 3.6. They give syntax errors in earlier versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

f-strings are certainly not Python2; they were introduced in Python 3.6.

Try: `s = ' '.join('%s=%s' % (key, value) for (key, value) in x.items())`